# CRYPTID series early to mid 2000s

Tags: story-identification, novel

So the novel begins with a teenager (who is 14/15) being left home alone - yet again - eating curry - yet again. He's watching tv and catches a newsreel from the Philippines, where in the background he spots his parents. his parents are supposed to be exterminators . He gets suspicious and does some sleuthing.
He finds a phone in the false bottom of a suitcase and decides to hit redial. Long story short, he finds out that his family is actually a part of an organization that studies 'Cryptids' and that his dog is a hybrid 'Cryptid'.

Comment: Interesting story, you might want to also check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Seanan McGuire has the [InCryptid series](http://seananmcguire.com/incryptid.php).  This doesn't seem to match (they all know about the family business in those books).  Possibly McGuire got the name from someone else.

Comment: Cryptid is a generic term for as yet undiscovered and non-classified creatures.

Answer (score 3):

[Creatch Battler](https://books.google.com/books?id=PdZRyLhluAgC) by Mark Crilley

> Billy Clikk’s just your ordinary, run-of-the-mill . . . hero? A guy
>   whose hobbies include skateboarding, extreme mountain biking—and a
>   brand of snowboarding he wishes would include a few good old-fashioned
>   body slams. Unfortunately, 12-year-old Billy’s boring home town of
>   Piffling, Indiana, will probably never host the X Games. But that
>   doesn’t stop him from bungee jumping off a bridge and winning the
>   X-Sports Challenge in front of Dave’s Cycle and Fitness.
>
> Then one day, things suddenly get more interesting. Billy discovers
>   his insect-exterminating parents—supposedly the best in Piffling—have
>   been living a double life. In just a few short hours, he’s sucked into
>   a world that his parents have been trying to hide from him. And this
>   world is much bigger, stranger, and scarier than the one he left
>   behind. How could his own dull parents have so many secrets that even
>   their secrets have secrets?
>
> On the bright side, this could be Billy’s chance to fight some real
>   bad guys: the huge kind with teeth and too many hairy tentacles to
>   count. Within a few hours of learning the truth, he’s flying to India
>   and testing out some very cool James Bond–style gadgetry, things no
>   average 12-year-old can even imagine. But before Billy can fight
>   alongside his parents, he’ll have to prove himself. Being a hero
>   doesn’t always mean getting the bad guy—sometimes it means keeping a
>   cool head to figure out what’s *really* going on. And at the end of the
>   day, Billy just might get to save the world—or go down trying.